# how to change a BGP path in juniper?

Tags: bgp, juniper, juniper-junos, route

How to change the selected BGP route?

[image]

I show the route `43.242.33.39`, there shows 3 GBP paths.

but I can not `ping` the ip(`43.242.33.39`).  and can not traceroute it.

how can I do with this?

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into your question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Comment: Not being able to ping or traceroute does not mean the router won’t forward packets.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The selected path is chosen because (all else being equal) the local preference (190) is set highest on this path.  To change which path BGP selects you will need to modify the local preference.

Comment: how to modify the local preference?

Comment: We will need a diagram of your network, along with the device configurations.  The local preference was configured to be what it is.  Before you change it, you need to know the reason behind it.